# GraphDiff Update Graph returning f:\Work\GitHub\GraphDiff\GraphDiff\GraphDiff\DbContextExtensions.cs

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

Hi I don't have much experience in development.This is my first project as i am fresher.I am trying to update entity in Sql Databse using GraphDiff.But it is returning me **"You need to find DbContextExtensions.cs to view the source for the current call stack frame"** while debugging.
Anyone please help me.Below is the code i am using for this.

```
using (var context = DataContext)
{
context.UpdateGraph(memberEntity);
context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the message of what Visual Studio debugger try to show you where the bug was in the specified source code. What you should be aware of is the detail information regarding to the exception you encountered or the debugger captured but not the source code...